# MYSQL Import via csv or any format

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a 2 database in mysql ,Now i need to import a table from one database to another but the thing is in first database the table contains 12 fields whereas in second database table it contains 8 fields in random order and the fields in both the tables are same except a few.How do i fix this ??

Answer (score 1):

If both databases are on the same instance of MySQL then just use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...` syntax and a fully qualified names for tables in format `<db_name>.<table_name>`. That's assuming that appropriate rights have been granted.

```sql
INSERT INTO db2.table_name (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT (column1, column2, column3)
  FROM db1.table_name
```

Comment: @user3003663 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?